# Is this the right way to deselect radio buttons in a listview?

Tags: android, listview, radio-button

I have a `DialogFragment` which I am populating with a `ListView` and a `Cursor Adaptor`. I was having issue with selecting a radio button and deselecting others. So I did this thing which works. But I wanted to know if I really need a loop there or there is another better way to do it. Here is my code:

```
viewHolder.radioButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            { @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int i = 0; i < selectionArrayAr.size(); i++){
                    selectionArrayAr.put(i, false);
                }

                selectionArrayAr.put(position, true);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }
    );
```

I am setting all values to `false` in the Sparse Array and then finally setting the clicked `radio button` to `true`.

Comment: Instead of this, you can create one field in your adapter data with selection status and update the radio button in onBindView method of adapter. It will be better

Comment: http://abhiandroid.com/ui/radiobutton-inside-listview.html  follow this link

Comment: http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html.

Comment: @Ankita thank you, I don't have problem with scrolling. I handled that.

Comment: @AmitBhandari, thanks for your response. I have to get all data from the user before I update the `Database` that my adapter uses. I have to show three more dialogs to the user and then finally on "Save" button click will I update the DB.